# Codeigniter Foreach within an Email Message

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

When using the `foreach` within the message:

```
$this->email->message('The following orders have backorders:<br><br>'.foreach ($backOrdersArray as $row2)
{
echo $OrderNumber.
'<br>Kind Regaards,<br>Merchant Lite');
};
```

Error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)
```

The code provided originally sends the email but only with one order number (and not multiple)

_

Update with print of backorders array as requested:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#27 (1) { ["ORDER"]=> string(9) "SPA1" } } 

array(6) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#64 (1) { ["ORDER"]=> string(11) "BHS2" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#65 (1) { ["ORDER"]=> string(11) "BHS3" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#66 (1) { ["ORDER"]=> string(11) "BHS4" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#67 (1) { ["ORDER"]=> string(11) "BHS5" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#68 (1) { ["ORDER"]=> string(11) "BHS6" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#69 (1) { ["ORDER"]=> string(11) "BHS7" } } 

array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#71 (1) { ["ORDER"]=> string(9) "10G1" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#72 (1) { ["ORDER"]=> string(9) "10G2" } }
```

These are generated within a `foreach` (To get the back orders for each customer)

-

I'm getting some problems trying to get this working. Is there anyway to get a `foreach` to loop through a list of numbers and print them in the message?

For example, I have a list of order numbers from a database `query`. I want to show these in the `message` of the email.  I have tried to put the `foreach` within the message, but that results in an error message.

This is my current code. I have also tried the `foreach` within the message with no success:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from($CustomersEmail);
$this->email->to($NoReply);

$this->email->subject('Back Orders');

foreach ($backOrdersArray as $row2)
{
    $OrderNumber = $row2->ORDER;
    echo $OrderNumber;
    echo '<br>';
    $this->email->message('The following orders have backorders:<br><br>'.$OrderNumber.'.);
};

$this->email->send();
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: what is in `$backOrdersArray` print_r and post data

Comment: @AbdullaNilam $backOrdersArray is a list of back orders (Includes the Order Number, which is what I want to send in the email). Updated First post with this.

Comment: post the data. So i can check your issue

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, I have.

Comment: what is the error or output you gets now ??

Comment: With the code provide, the email sends but only with 1 order number (Not multiple as shown above). The other error with the foreach in the message is posted in the first post.

Comment: ya it does. Wait will give you some helps on this

Comment: Thank you @AbdullaNilam. I have added the error when using the foreach within the message.

Comment: Hi @AbdullaNilam, Thanks for the help, but I am receiving the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from($CustomersEmail);
$this->email->to($NoReply);
$this->email->subject('Back Orders');


$msg = "The following orders have backorders:<br><br>";
foreach ($backOrdersArray as $row2)
{
    $OrderNumber = $row2->ORDER;
    $msg .='<br>';
    $msg .=  $OrderNumber;
};

$this->email->message($msg);
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this results in the following error `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH) in on line 43`.

Comment: @Jake: u can try now :)

Comment: bro, i have fixed the semicolon issue `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39918989/revisions`

Comment: This worked when I made use $msg was empty before the foreach (And the semi colon). Thanks for the help To both of you!

Comment: @Jake happy to help :)